# Angular pass component context to subscribe complete()?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page that show all your insert record from a table and if (case 1) you have no insert record show a button like please start, else (case 2) it show you the table with all your records stored in db. The page is the same but it check from http response if is case 1 or 2.

Im having problems in checking oncomplete subscribe in which case i am so im asking if is it possible to pass the module context in () => {} function like

```js
this.is_loading = true
this.show_content = 0

constructor(private webapi: WebApiService){
this.webapi
    .getData()
    .pipe(concatMap((result: dataResult.KeyValueResult<string, string>[]) => from(result)))
    .subscribe(
        (element: dataResult.KeyValueResult<string, string>) => {
            this.is_loading = false;
            this.show_content = 2
        },
        (error: any) => {
            console.error('error on widgetList', error);
        },
        () => {
            // here, i can't see this
            if(this.show_content != 2) { // if 2 then i have rows
                this.show_content = 1
                this.is_loading = false
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: did you try console log inside         () => {...} before the condition ?

Comment: ``const self = this;`` could help you but I wonder why you can not access ``this`` since you are using arrow functions.

Comment: i put a debugger and i see my scope is a SafeSubscriber instance